# Working out average reviews javascript

Tags: javascript, math, rating

I am trying to loop through 3 places and select the place with the highest average reviews and rating.

Say i have the following.

```
var places = [{
  name: "place 1",
  reviews: 100,
  rating: 5,
},{
  name: "place 2",
  reviews: 10000,
  rating: 5,
},{
  name: "place 3",
  reviews: 10000000,
  rating: 4,
}];

for (i = 0; i < places.length; i++) { 

    // loop through and calculate the highest average reviews
    var rating = places[i].rating;
    var reviews = places[i].reviews;

    // work out the average score place 3 should be the highest

}
```

http://jsbin.com/loyequluke/edit?js,console,output

Any suggestions what i want to do is find the highest average rating, out of the 3 places.

The correct result would be place 3, but i dont know how to work this out any help please?

Comment: Take a moment to look at what you've written. What do you think `(A * B) / B` would even do?

Comment: any suggestions both this is why i am asking the question? @AndréDion can you explain why i dont have the required data.

Comment: What do "reviews" and "rating" actually mean? What does it mean to have "reviews: 10000000" and "rating: 4"?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol so that place has been reviewed 10000000 and been given a rating of average raring of 4 stars.

Comment: @user1503606 Then how is ‘place 3’ the correct result for the highest average rating?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the code below and let me know if this works for you or not. Since I don't know how you are calculating the highest score, I assume it's `(rating * reviews) / rating` according to which you get the value. You may run the code snippet given and see the result for yourself. Basically, you have the idea to calculate, this best works for small records with few hundred.

```js
var places = [{
  name: "place 1",
  reviews: 100,
  rating: 5,
},
{
  name: "place 3",
  reviews: 30000000,
  rating: 23,
},

{
  name: "place 2",
  reviews: 10000,
  rating: 5,
},{
  name: "place 3",
  reviews: 10000000,
  rating: 4,
}];

var highest = [];
for (i = 0; i < places.length; i++) { 
    
    // loop through and calculate the highest average reviews
    var rating = places[i].rating;
    var reviews = places[i].reviews;

    highest.push((rating * reviews) / rating);
  
    // work out the average score place 3 should be the highest

}

var highestRating = highest[0];
var pos = 0;

for (i = 0; i < highest.length; i += 1) {
    if (highestRating < highest[i]) {
        highestRating = highest[i];
        pos = i;
    }
}

console.log('Highest Rating: ', highestRating);
console.log('Found at position: ', pos);
console.log('Place with highest score : ', places[pos]);
```

Let us know if this works for you or not.

Comment: Could `(rating * reviews) / rating` be simplified somehow?

Comment: I don't know, the average calculation is upto OP, so can't really tell anything about it.

Comment: Well `(rating * reviews) / rating == reviews`. And are two loops really necessary?